# Apache/mod_wsgi daemon mode not working

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have problems getting mod_wsgi to run in daemon mode on my Debian/Apache/Python2.6/Django setup. In my virtual host config file I have

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName mysite.com

  WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com processes=2 threads=15
  WSGIProcessGroup mysite.com

  WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/mysite/wsgi/django.wsgi

  <Directory /path/to/mysite/wsgi/>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

set up. To test activation of daemon mode, I use this wsgi script:

```
import sys
import os

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'mysite.settings')

def application(environ, start_response):
    print >> sys.stderr, 'mod_wsgi.process_group = %s' % repr(environ['mod_wsgi.process_group']) 

    from django.core.handlers.wsgi import WSGIHandler
    _application = WSGIHandler()

    return _application(environ, start_response)
```

and the resulting log file always says:

```
mod_wsgi.process_group = ''
```

which, accroding to the documentation, indicates that daemon mode is not being used. I checked my setup multiple times, the versions of Apache, mod_wsgi and Python are matching and my setup is correct according to all the HOWTO's I've read out there. What could I be missing?

---

Edit: FYI my application is running fine in embedded mode, I just wanted to switch to daemon mode and found out it is not activated using the wsgi script above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that a symlink wasn't set correctly so my config changes never loaded in Apache.  Sorry for wasting your time, I thought I checked everything thoroughly before posting.

Answer (score 0):

The line `mod_wsgi.process_group = ''` implies that you are still operating in embedded mode (as you note). `mod_wsgi` daemon mode will not work on `Apache 1.x` so I assume that you are running `2.x` (as you also note).

You could try setting the apache

```
LogLevel info
```

so that there is more helpful information in the log file. I'm also assuming that you've forced apache to restart

```
# /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

this shouldn't be necessary in daemon mode so much, but if you were in embedded mode previously you will need to reload your config files.

Comment: All of your assumptions are true and I repeatedly restarted apache while trying to debug this. I also set `LogLevel info`, with no additional information showing up in the log files. Unfortunately I am still stuck on this problem...